# Java method in a spring boot aplication that receives the result of another method as parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm building a Spring Boot server. In my controller I convert the result from DAOs to DTOs, and then put them in a ResponseEntity. However I have void methods in my service.

So I have this code:

```
protected final <T> ResponseEntity<T> of(T param) {
    if (param != null)
        return status(HttpStatus.OK).body(param);
    else
        return status(status).build();
    }

protected final <S, T> ResponseEntity<S> of(T param, Class<S> target) {
    if (param != null)
        return status(HttpStatus.OK).body(convert(param, target));
    else
        return status(status).build();
}
```

The first receives a parameter and builds an ResponseEntity with status OK(200) and if T != null, puts T as the body. The seconds does similar, but converts S to T meaning DAO to DTO using ModelMapper. My question is can I make any modification or add some code to make this possible:

```
//in my service layer

public void test() {
    //do stuff here
}

//then in the controller

public ResponseEntity<Void> test() {
    return ok(service.test());
}
```

Right now when I do this, it tells me it can't convert void to T.

Comment: What's the point of calling `service.test()` *inside* `ok()`? Just call it in a separate line. Also, to the best of my knowledge, `ResponseEntity.ok(body)` does the exact same thing as your first `of` method

Comment: The point i basically a pattern that i can copy paste my controllers no matter the return type and will work with minimum changes. And yes it does if there is body, if there is no body it won't work

Comment: Well, there's no way to make it work, you can stop trying now

Comment: I found a workarround, thats not pretty though

Answer (score 0):

If you just replace your return Type to *ResponseEntity* , it should work.

```
public ResponseEntity test() {
    return ok(service.test());
}
```

This should also allow you to return a String message in the body as well, even though it's not of type T.

Comment: Yes this does compile, but puts the T as Object instead of a generic, so its hard to tell when conversion is needed. I thought of this but wanted to do it as last option. Also after checking still doesn't work. Says cant convert void do Object, which is what java puts a generic paremeter if none is there